# EDIT: numpy operations on astropy time series objects

Tags: python, numpy, datetime, astropy

EDIT: the original title of this question was '**Unable to multiply two python arrays together**',and the corresponding question is below. The error arose from the fact that list2 contained data that had implicit units of 'astropy.Time' and each element in the list was a 'time object'. The answer provided is a standard quick fix to enable regular numpy operations to be performed on such data (e.g., in the below case, where the time series output was from a lightkurve process)

I have two lists of numpy arrays in Python, one of which has 36 elements and the other one has 5, i.e.

```
list1 = [array1, array2, array3, array4, array5], 
list2 = [arrayA, arrayB, arrayC, arrayD, ...]
```

I am trying to multiply every element in list2 by, for instance, element 0 in list 1 (so array1 * list2). However, no matter how I try to implement this (for loop, while loop), Python returns the error '*Fatal Python error: Segmentation fault*'.
The same thing happens even if I try the test case: `list1[0]*list2[0]`, or alternatively, `np.multiply(list1[0], list2[0])`
I have checked the length and dimensions of all the pertaining elements and they all are the same as each other (they're both 1D numpy arrays, and for e.g. `len(list1[0]) = 2000` and `len(list2[0]) = 2000` ), so I'm really confused on why I can't perform this basic multiplication? I am using the Spyder IDE, if that makes any difference, and would be super grateful for any advice, thanks!

Comment: What is the dtype of the arrays? `array1`, `arrayA` etc.  also lets check `array1.shape` etc.  `len` just checks 1 dimension.

Comment: Thanks, that was really helpful! Completely forgot to check the dtype of the arrays, list2 just has floats but list1 is populated by 'time objects' from some previous analysis using the lightkurve package, I guess this might be where the problem lies...

Answer (score 1):

In the above case where one of the lists contains elements from a lightkurve time-series, the dtype of the elements is astropy.time

To convert, the 'to_value()' method needs to be used, where you want to convert your astropy time series to a series of floats and you know the unit of your data is MJD (Modified Julian Date):

```
converted_times = []

for i in range(len(list2)):
    newlist = [x.to_value('jd') for x in list2[i]]
    converted_times.append(newlist)
```

You can then use your astropy time series and do standard numpy manipulations with them

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for `np.outer`. See [here](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.outer.html):

```
import numpy as np 
list1 = np.ones((5,))
list2 = np.linspace(-2,2,5)
rl = np.outer(list1, list2)
rl
```

Also, welcome to SO but please note that it would be better if you were to provide some sample code for people to work with. See [how to write a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply, np.outer was also returning the same error as before (Fatal Python error: Segmentation fault), but I now think it's due to the type of arrays I am using. Each element in each array in list2 is not a number, but an object (specifically, a 'time object', but this is most likely because I have obtained these values using Python's lightkurve package)

Comment: I'll provide an answer to my question when I figure out how to manipulate the time objects in list2, hopefully it'll be helpful for the small niche of people who also use lightkurve (I didn't realise that this would be a problem until I checked the dtype of the arrays)